# How to ensure specific character encoding in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, encoding

What I need is to ensure that a string gets encoded in a known character encoding. So far, my research and testing with MS SQL Server has revealed that the documented encoding is 'UCS-2', however the actual encoding (on the server in question) is 'UCS-2LE'.

Which doesn't seem very reliable. What I would love is an `ENCODE` function as found in PERL, Node, or most anything, so that regardless of upgrades or settings changes, my hash function will be working on known input.

We can limit the hashing string to HEX, so at worst, we could manually map the 16 possible input characters to the proper bytes. Anyone have a recommendation on this?

Here's the PERL I'm using:

```
use Digest::SHA qw/sha256/;
use Encode qw/encode/;

$seed = 'DDFF5D36-F14D-495D-BAA6-3688786D6CFA';
$string = '123456789';

$target = '57392CD6A5192B6185C5999EB23D240BB7CEFD26E377D904F6FEF262ED176F97';

$encoded = encode('UCS-2LE', $seed.$string);
$sha256 = uc(unpack("H*", sha256($encoded)));

print "$target\n$sha256\n";
```

Which matches MS SQL:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA_256', 'DDFF5D36-F14D-495D-BAA6-3688786D6CFA123456789')
```

But what I really want is:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA_256', ENCODE('UCS2-LE', 'DDFF5D36-F14D-495D-BAA6-3688786D6CFA123456789'))
```

So that no matter what MS SQL happens to be encoding the input string as, the `HASHBYTES` will always operate on a known byte array.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses UCS-2 only on columns, variables and literals that were declared as `nvarchar`. In all other cases it uses 8-bit ASCII with the encoding of the current database, unless specified otherwise (using the `collate` clause, for example).

So, you either have to specify a Unicode literal:

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA_256', N'DDFF5D36-F14D-495D-BAA6-3688786D6CFA123456789');
```

Or, you can use a variable or table column of the `nvarchar` data type:

```
-- Variable
declare @var nvarchar(128) = N'DDFF5D36-F14D-495D-BAA6-3688786D6CFA123456789';

select HASHBYTES('SHA_256', @var);

-- Table column
declare @t table(
  Value nvarchar(128)
);

insert into @t
select @var;

select HASHBYTES('SHA_256', t.Value)
from @t t;
```

P.S. Of course, since Wintel is a little-endian platform, SQL Server uses the same version of the encoding as the OS / hardware. Unless something new will come out in SQL Server 2017, there is no way to get big-endian representation in this universe natively.